# How to checking function called in Promise by sinon

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, sinon

I was using `mocha` + `chai` + `sinon` to test function, but in promise use `called` property, even if write a undefined function, `called` always `true`, What is it caused by ？and how to resolve？ thx

```
describe("when click get verifycode", function () {
it('if get server response success, should start countdown', function (done) {
    // given
    sandbox.stub(model, 'getVerifyCode').resolves({});
    sandbox.spy(view, 'startCountDown');
    // when
    var result = instance.onClickVerify('123456');
    // then
    result.then(res => {
        // no matter what function, called always true
        // e.g. expect(AnUndefinedFunction.called).to.be.ok;
        expect(instance.view.startCountDown.called).to.be.ok;
        done();
    }).catch(err => {
        done();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the `.catch` block is catching any error that occurs in the `.then` block.

This is an issue because you are calling `done` without passing the `err` object. Mocha interprets this as the test passing correctly, rather than failing.

---

The fix:

```
describe("when click get verifycode", function () {
    it('if get server response success, should start countdown', function (done) {
        // given
        sandbox.stub(model, 'getVerifyCode').resolves({});
        sandbox.spy(view, 'startCountDown');
        // when
        var result = instance.onClickVerify('123456');
        // then
        result.then(res => {
            // no matter what function, called always true
            // e.g. expect(AnUndefinedFunction.called).to.be.ok;
            expect(instance.view.startCountDown.called).to.be.ok;
            done();
        }).catch(err => {
            done(err);
        });
    })
});
```